# Problem 401 when streaming Tweets with Python

Tags: python, stream, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I keep receiving error 401 when trying to stream the Tweets. I have checked the consumer key and secret and are ok.

```
    import tweepy,json
access_token='X'
access_token_secret='Y'
consumer_key='W'
consumer_secret='Z'
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token=(access_token,access_token_secret)
api=tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self,data):
        print (data)
        return True
    
    def on_error(self,status):
        print(status)
        
listener=StdOutListener()
auth=OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token=(access_token,access_token_secret)

stream=Stream(auth,listener)
stream.filter(track=['Trump','Sanchez'])
print(stream)
```